# Django : Ignore a __in type filter in the queryset if it searches the empty list

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

Having this code sequence:

```
queryset = self.filter(
            brand_id__in=(
                UserObjectPermission.objects.filter(
                    content_type=brand_ctype,
                    user=user,
                ).values_list('object_pk')
            )
        )
```

If there is no UserObjectPermission object that matches the filter `content_type=brand_ctype, user=user` then the end result will be empty queryset, because brand_id __in will search in [empty queryset].

But I need the reverse. If there is no UserObjectPermision object for this filter (`content_type=brand_ctype, user=user`) then return all objects, that is, ignore this filter (

```
brand_id__in=(UserObjectPermission.objects.filter(
                    content_type=brand_ctype,
                    user=user,
                ).values_list('object_pk')
            )
```

I need the brand_id__in filter to run only if there is at least one object in the queryset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the OR (`|`) operator

```
from django.db.models import Q, Exists

brands_qs = UserObjectPermission.objects.filter(
    content_type=brand_ctype,
    user=user,
).values_list('object_pk')

queryset = self.filter(
    Q(brand_id__in=brands_qs) | ~Exists(brands_qs)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the queryset contains any items:

```
brands = UserObjectPermission.objects.filter(
    content_type=brand_ctype,
    user=user,
).values_list('object_pk')

if brands:
    queryset = queryset.filter(brand_id__in=brands)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this solution does not fit into the context of the rest of the project
I am looking for a solution offered by the possibilities of ORM. Is it possible to do this directly in the queryset?

Comment: @johny: no, I furthermore don't see why this would not work. You can override the `get_queryset` in a CBV and thus add checks.